# looking for a client side only web development framework

Tags: javascript, frameworks, client

I am looking to building a rich app style presentation.  i would like it to be a single page web app and would like to use a good web development framework to build it. However, I do not want to have any server side dependencies.  corMVC seems to describe exactly what I want, but it has no documentation so I cannot be sure.

The best I can do is describe what I am looking for, I suspect I am not using the correct terminology in my searches:

- A JavaScript web development  framework for developing a client side only single page web application.
- It should be well documented, maintained and up to date
- It should work either as an MVC or a static website generator like Jekyll
- It should work with routes with ready to go back button functionality
- If it worked with templates and layouts that would be great

#### EDIT - I left something out:

- Must parse markdown files (like Jekyll)

---

The reason?  I would like to deploy this in a few different places, most don't have servers.  I would like to build it in an organized way just as I would with Jekyll or web2py.

Comment: From what I read about StaticSite, it's not really "client side only"... All files have to be on Amazon S3 (that's a server - or a cloud whatever), and its also using node.js (server side javascript)

Comment: ok thanks, i'm removing it.  still on the lookout though!

Comment: @user1026169 Might want to try ExtJS. It has MVC with a bunch of customizable components. Also the docs are very good. Supports deep links, templates, and layouts too. http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addy Osmani has implemented "ToDo" applications in the most popular Javascript MV* frameworks so that you can compare them:

http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/

have a look at these:

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

http://javascriptmvc.com/

Comment: i see, does this give examples of frameworks that i could use then: http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/    ?

Comment: yes. actually... that's a much better link. I forgot about the work done by addyosmani.  He's got a great blog too: http://addyosmani.com/blog/

Comment: anything out there that can also transform markdown (or some other markup language) to html like a static website generator would?  it could be via a filter or any other means.

Comment: I don't believe any of those frameworks would handle markdown out of the box but I know for sure that they some can be tweaked to handle markdown. 

You can use this showdown (https://github.com/coreyti/showdown) library to convert the markdown to HTML. I know backbone.js lets you set a custom parse() and template library functions that can be modified to use this showdown library and thus spit out your markdown in html.